# Website Loading Speed

Tags: php, ubuntu, ethernet

I've finished building my website only to discover the loading time is around 8 seconds, this is not good obviously...  I'm running the server from my house on a Dell Vostro 200 with Ubuntu and Apache2 which is a secondary OS to Windows XP.  The computer is connected to a netgear wireless extender with an Ethernet cord. I have a 1.37 Mbps upload speed.  The website itself uses several mysql databases and lots of css, and all of the pages are .php and linked by includes.  Basically I'm overwhelmed with everything and I would be extremely grateful if anyone could tell me where my problem is, or if it's just everything combined.  You can visit the site at `www.dawnspy.com`.  Thanks!

Comment: Really? Come on. 1. How in the world are we suposed to help with this. 2. Pay $5/month for hosting. You're paying more in electricity costs.

Comment: Clearly off topic & None of the SO categories cover this type of closure.

Comment: Upload of 1.37Mbps across, say, 25 users. If you think it's slow now, wait until then. Move it to a proper hosting company. If you still think it's slow then look at PageSpeed and fix everything it suggests.

Comment: Lets say I have $1000 to invest for hosting, could I get better performance using a hosting company at $20/Month as I could buying my own server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your banners are taking 8 seconds to load:

[image: Banner Load Time]

Possibly look at a CDN or some alternate means of hosting your banner images. In the future, I recommend using an HTTP debugger such as [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/).